# Login function with react and django framework ,[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using django as backend and react-native as frontend. And the backend is already working for the login functionality. But now I try to implement the login functionality in react-native. So I have: a service:

```
export const loginRequest = async (email, password) => {
    const response = await fetch("172.25.80.1:19000/api/user/token/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: email,
            password: password,
        }),
    });

    const data = await response.json();

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(data.message);
    }
    return data;
};
```

and a context:

```
export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);


    const onLogin = (email, password) => {
        loginRequest(email, password)
            .then((loginUser) => {
                console.log(loginUser.data);
                setIsLoading(true);
                setUser(loginUser);
                setIsLoading(false);
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                //console.log(e);
                setIsLoading(false);
                setError(e);
            });
    };

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isLoading, error, user, onLogin }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

and the view of login:

```
<AccountContainer>
                <AuthInput
                    label="E-mail"
                    value={email}
                    textContentType="emailAddress"
                    keyboardType="email-address"
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    onChangeText={(u) => setEmail(u)}
                />
                <Spacer size="large">
                    <AuthInput
                        label="Password"
                        value={password}
                        textContentType="password"
                        secureTextEntry
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                        onChangeText={(p) => setPassword(p)}
                    />
                </Spacer>
                {error && (
                    <ErrorContainer size="large">
                        <Text variant="error">{error}</Text>
                    </ErrorContainer>
                )}
                <Spacer size="large">
                    {!isLoading ? (
                        <AuthButton onPress={() => onLogin(email, password)}>Login</AuthButton>
                    ) : (
                        <ActivityIndicator animating={true} color={Colors.blue300} />
                    )}
                </Spacer>
            </AccountContainer>
```

But I get this error after I trigger the login button:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Error]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.]
```

Question: how to resolve this?

I have it now like:

```
const onLogin = (email, password) => {
        console.log("HELLO2");
        loginRequest(email, password)
            .then((loginUser) => {
                console.log("HELLO");
                setIsLoading(true);
                setUser(loginUser);
                setIsLoading(false);
            })
            .catch(({ e }) => {
                setIsLoading(false);
                setError(e);
            });
    };
```

and:

```
<Spacer size="large">
                    {!isLoading ? (
                        <AuthButton onPress={() => onLogin(email, password)}>Login</AuthButton>
                    ) : (
                        <ActivityIndicator animating={true} color={Colors.blue300} />
                    )}
                </Spacer>
```

and the service:

```
export const loginRequest = async (email, password) => {
    console.log("login");
    const response = await fetch("172.25.80.1:19000/api/user/token/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: email,
            password: password,
        }),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(response);

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(data.message);
    }
    return data;
};
```

in the console I see login after I press the login button. But it stays on the login screen. Doesn't prints the response data.

And in django I am using:

```
'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
```

And that works. I am using swagger. And if I go to: '/api/user/token/''. Then it generate the token:

```
    
Response body

{
  "token": "0c146b1f7050af06e19020db125d693c7b554346"
}
```

Oke, I changed this:

```
export const loginRequest = async (email, password) => {
    console.log("login");
    const response = await fetch("http://172.25.80.1:19000/api/user/token/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: email,
            password: password,
        }),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(data.message);
    }
    return data;
};
```

But then I geet this error:

```
Object {
  "email": Array [
    "Enter a valid email address.",
  ],
  "password": Array [
    "This field is required.",
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part of your code

```
const onLogin = (email, password) => {
    loginRequest(email, password)
        .then((loginUser) => {
            console.log(loginUser.data);
            setIsLoading(true);
            setUser(loginUser);
            setIsLoading(false);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            //console.log(e);
            setIsLoading(false);
            setError(e);
        });
};
```

Your doing setError to 'e' but e would be an object and not a string. And then in the body here

```
{error && (
     <ErrorContainer size="large">
          <Text variant="error">{error}</Text>
     </ErrorContainer>
)}
```

You are trying to show an object to the screen which is not a valid react element

I would remove showing the error in the body so you can print out what 'e' is from the catch statement and then de-structure it so you can actually show e.errorMessage or whatever is the actual string from that object that you want to show to the user.